# How to get all the rows if col1 of a row equals a value and col2 of same row or different row equals another value, for a same col3 value in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

| R | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | 1 | A | B | 1 |
| R2 | 1 | B | C | 2 |
| R3 | 1 | C | D | 3 |
| R4 | 2 | A | D | 1 |
| R5 | 3 | A | D | 1 |
| R6 | 3 | D | X | 2 |

I have a table `my_table` in mySQL which has the above row-column details. I need to get all the values of `c1` that have a starting `c2` value = `A` and and ending `c3` value = `D`.

> The rows of the table are sorted by `R`, so the *start* `c2` value for `c1=1` is `A` and the *end* `c3` value of `c1=1` is `D`

### I am expecting an output of

| C1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

For `c1=1` there are 3 rows:

| R | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | 1 | A | B | 1 |
| R2 | 1 | B | C | 2 |
| R3 | 1 | C | D | 3 |

You can see here the first `C2` is `A` and the last `C3` is `D`
This satisfies the criteria, so the `C1` value of `1` should be included in the output.

For `c1=2` there is 1 row:

| R | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R4 | 2 | A | D | 1 |

It has a `C2` of `A` and `C3` is `D` so this should also be included in the output.

For `c1=3` there are 2 rows:

| R | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R5 | 3 | A | D | 1 |
| R6 | 3 | D | X | 2 |

The first `C2` is `A` and the last `C3` is `X`
This does not satisfy the criteria, so the `C1` value of `3` should ***NOT*** be included in the output.

I only need C1 values that satisfy the conditions.

Comment: r2 has neither a or d in it, r5 has both in  it, why was it excluded

Comment: @nbk but it has same c1 values. and very beginning and end is A and D respectively.

Comment: So you want all c1, that has in c2 an a or c3 a d, ok, but why is r5 missing

Comment: @nbk r5 has same c1 though its very beginning is A but its end is X, considering same c1

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make sense, please reword your question. *I need to get all the rows that have c2 value = A and c3 value = D.* is only satisfied by R4/R5, you are mixing AND and OR perhaps.

Comment: For that you should use a recursive cte to get all linked rows and can so determine what is at the start and what at the end

Comment: @yacc I want all rows which have the same c1, with the first row c2 value = 'A' and last row c3 value = 'D'. If c1 is unique, that single row should be returned if c2 and c3 of that particular row values are A and D respectively.

Comment: Be careful about saying *first* and *last* row, because the database does not know any such order. The rows are ordered internally but not visible to the user.

Comment: c2 value should be A, c3 value should be D, but they need not be in the same row. If they are not in the same row, they should have the same c1 value. Here R1,R2,R3 have same c1 value and R1C2 = A and R3C3 =D. Hence they satisfy the condition. Also, R4 have a single entry which has R4C2 = A and R4C3 = D. So they also satisfy the condition. In the case of R5 and R6, C1 has the same value in R5 and R6, but R5C2=A , R6C3 != D hence does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: It's still unclear why R2 fits the criteria, unless you have a certain ordering that provides R1<R2<R3 and so makes R1 a *first* and R3 a *last* row of a certain group with same C1.

Comment: @yacc We only need c1 values which match the criteria.

Comment: It's all clear now, unfortunately I have no clue how to make this into a query. I'll upvote your question if that helps.

Comment: Do not remove this ordering information, it is crucial to build the query.

Comment: How did you know that R1<R2<R3 before you added the ordering column? Is it from a sheet? I'll watch how this goes and if no one answers I'll try something (no guarantees).

Comment: @yacc I didn't know that it was crucial hence I didn't add it. That Column was already there in the table.

Comment: It's all ok now, just hang on, someone will know.

Comment: It is vital for questions like this that you include the expected output, even if you construct it manually and consider using a truth table to explain your logic, rather than trying to write it out in text. Break the logic down into discrete steps that transform the logic, rather than trying to get to your end goal in a single bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input selection is ordered, and we consider the grouping sets of `C1` values to be in the same sequence, starting with the first row `C2` and ending ing the last row `C3` values, then we can construct this sequence for each value of `C1`:

| C1 | MinR | C2 | MaxR | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | R1 | A | R3 | D |
| 2 | R4 | A | R4 | D |
| 3 | R5 | A | R6 | X |

From that, we can *now* apply the original logic of:

> rows that have c2 value = A and c3 value = D.

Which should be only the first 2 rows:

| C1 | MinR | C2 | MaxR | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | R1 | A | R3 | D |
| 2 | R4 | A | R4 | D |

And therefore the answer for the values of `C1` is

| C1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

In MySQL you can do this with the following query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b17c37/6

```
SELECT Selector.C1
FROM (
  SELECT C1
  , MIN(R) as MinR
  , MAX(R) as MaxR
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY C1
) Selector
INNER JOIN my_table minR ON Selector.C1 = minr.C1 AND Selector.MinR = minR.R
INNER JOIN my_table maxR ON Selector.C1 = maxr.C1 AND Selector.MaxR = maxR.R
WHERE minR.C2 = 'A' AND maxR.C3 = 'D';
```

---

I actually explored this in MS SQL in the following fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/KwXfdx6D
The expression for the proof table is:

```
SELECT Selector.C1, MinR, minR.C2, MaxR, maxR.C3
FROM (
  SELECT C1
  , MIN(R) as MinR
  , MAX(R) as MaxR
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY C1
) Selector
INNER JOIN my_table minR ON Selector.C1 = minr.C1 AND Selector.MinR = minR.R
INNER JOIN my_table maxR ON Selector.C1 = maxr.C1 AND Selector.MaxR = maxR.R;
```

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate for me to edit your post to reflect my understanding, but please review my answer and if it matches your expectation please use some of the language or transformations in your post to make this logic clearer to the rest of the community.